# Filter firestore stream based on value in field

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of arrays and in that a field of `todos` which is an array of maps. I want to fetch all the todos from all the arrays, filter them according to a given value in the todos map which is `dataAndTimeEnabled`.

```
class ArrayController extends GetxController {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  late CollectionReference collectionReference;

  RxList<Array> arrays = RxList<Array>([]);
  List<Todo> scheduledTodos = [];

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    String uid = Get.find<AuthController>().user!.uid;
    collectionReference =
        _firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("arrays");
    arrays.bindStream(getArrays());
    arrays.forEach((element) {
      element.todos!
          .where((element) => element.dateAndTimeEnabled == true)
          .toList()
          .forEach((element) {
        scheduledTodos.add(element);
      });
    });
  }

  Stream<List<Array>> getArrays() {
    return collectionReference
        .snapshots()
        .map((query) => query.docs.map((item) => Array.fromMap(item)).toList());
  }
}
```

This is what I have tried but am receiving an empty list

[image]

Comment: I believe there can be issues when performing where clauses on arrays within a document. Why not just make todos a collection of documents and query that instead? Would be a cleaner solution as long as it doesn't cause issues elsewhere in your logic.

Comment: I tried structuring the data in that way but on fetching all the `todos` you would need the `collection IDs` of all the arrays in the `onInit` method and I wasn't sure how to get them, another problem was I wasn't sure how to reference the collection of `todos` in my array model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I wasn't able to filter the todos in the map of arrays, I figure out another way. I made another collection `allTodos` and stored all the `todos` from all the arrays in that and Set a custom id as the doc id for each todo in that way whenever a todo was updated or deleted in any list it would also be updated in the `allTodos` collection.

This is the code:

```
class ArrayController extends GetxController {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  late CollectionReference collectionReference;
  late CollectionReference allTodosCollectionReference;

  late Query doneQuery;
  late Query scheduledQuery;
  late Query todayQuery;

  RxList<Array> arrays = RxList<Array>([]);
  RxList<FilterTodo> allTodos = RxList<FilterTodo>([]);
  RxList<FilterTodo> doneTodos = RxList<FilterTodo>([]);
  RxList<FilterTodo> scheduledTodos = RxList<FilterTodo>([]);
  RxList<FilterTodo> todayTodos = RxList<FilterTodo>([]);

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    String uid = Get.find<AuthController>().user!.uid;
    collectionReference =
        _firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("arrays");
    allTodosCollectionReference =
        _firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("allTodos");
    doneQuery = allTodosCollectionReference.where("done", isEqualTo: true);
    scheduledQuery = allTodosCollectionReference.where("dateAndTimeEnabled",
        isEqualTo: true);
    todayQuery = allTodosCollectionReference.where("date",
        isEqualTo: DateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(DateTime.now()));
    arrays.bindStream(getArrays());
    allTodos.bindStream(getAllTodos());
    doneTodos.bindStream(getAllDoneTodos());
    scheduledTodos.bindStream(getAllScheduledTodos());
    todayTodos.bindStream(getAllTodayTodos());
  }

  Stream<List<Array>> getArrays() {
    return collectionReference
        .snapshots()
        .map((query) => query.docs.map((item) => Array.fromMap(item)).toList());
  }

  Stream<List<FilterTodo>> getAllTodos() {
    return allTodosCollectionReference.snapshots().map(
        (query) => query.docs.map((item) => FilterTodo.fromMap(item)).toList());
  }

  Stream<List<FilterTodo>> getAllDoneTodos() {
    return doneQuery.snapshots().map(
        (query) => query.docs.map((item) => FilterTodo.fromMap(item)).toList());
  }

  Stream<List<FilterTodo>> getAllScheduledTodos() {
    return scheduledQuery.snapshots().map(
        (query) => query.docs.map((item) => FilterTodo.fromMap(item)).toList());
  }

  Stream<List<FilterTodo>> getAllTodayTodos() {
    return todayQuery.snapshots().map(
        (query) => query.docs.map((item) => FilterTodo.fromMap(item)).toList());
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]